# Mixing 5.1 sound for film

Tags: 5.1, logic, dcp

Doing my first feature length film sound track. The person who's doing DCP asked that I deliver the 5.1 mix with a 2-pop sync. I have no idea what that is. Anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly 2 seconds before the first frame of picture you put 1 frame of 1khz tone. Used to sync audio and video. You can use a signal generator to do this such as the one in Pro Tools.